# Magento import products API Call model: product_api: create product 1 product takes 40 seconds

Tags: image, magento, import, product, magmi

Has someone an idea why the api call takes so much time to create 1 product?

At one customer it took 1-3 seconds a product, same code for another customer between 30 seconds and 1 minute.

I got it from the article "Scrubbing Bubbles for Magento’s SOAP" from Alan Storm http://alanstorm.com/magento_soap_api_shell_scripts

So you can skip the layers SOAP or XML-RPC and use direct calls in the core.

UPDATE(1): I saw the indexes were build a long time ago (for weeks), after it is going much faster. But not too fast. 6 seconds per product, 3 seconds again for only the creation of the product. In the other 3 seconds update stock api and add media api.

UPDATE(2): Indexes are rebuild (in program too automatically) but today it takes 40 seconds per product (how is this possible, webshop not slow)

UPDATE(3): This was a cache problem, each time the cache (storage cache) was cleared, again 3-6 seconds (no problem for only the first time, a bulk of products, later each night this will be a few new products).

UPDATE(4): Yes it goes very fast with Magmi, 18.000 products an hour and all images and extra images are created (included own records for ERP extension). But problems with directories for plugin gallery_images, took the most time to get it to work, my program is running from root + subdirectory and Magmi takes root + subdirectory as 'root', so I had to change Magmi, also to determine if there is no exception for creating a product because I had to do own things after (creating records for ERP extension).

UPDATE(5): What is the difference between Magento API (create product) and Magmi? Magmi creates direct records into the database, but if extensions doing extra things core extended maybe covered by the Magento API (create product), that kind of things you have to do by yourself I think, and because of that I find the Magento API (create product) safer too use, or not? (first time slow, after normal, but safe in any version)

QUESTION: I created this because I read on forums, Magmi and Martinez are fast but they have problemsn  both, you can't do all. So I use Magmi only for updating products, goes very fast (Martinez also). **But is this true or can you normally also create products easily with Magmi or Martinez?** (my program is always a second possibility for me). But I go to try this now (Magmi), because this is all going too slow.

Answer: Yes it seems to be that creating products is going easily with Magmi, for now .. I don't know yet what I miss because of other extensions ..

Code:

```
  $model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_api');

  $type = 'simple';
  $product_attribute_set_id = '9';
  $sku = ($products_array[$p][0]);
  $data = array('short_description' => $products_array[$p][3],
                'name' => $products_array[$p][1],
                'weight' => ((float)str_replace(",", ".", $products_array[$p][16])),
                'price' => ((float)str_replace(",", ".", $products_array[$p][7])) * $profit,
                'cost' => ((float)str_replace(",", ".", $products_array[$p][8])),
                'description' => $products_array[$p][2],
                'tax_class_id' => $tax_class_id,
                'status' => '1',
                'eancode' => $products_array[$p][4],
                'afas_sku' => $products_array[$p][0],
                'leverancier' => $supplier,
                'inhoud_verpakking' => $products_array[$p][0],
                'size' => $products_array[$p][13],
                'material' => $products_array[$p][15],
                'kleur' => $color,
                'manufacturer' => $manufacturer,
                'delivery' => $delivery,
                'pptitleadditional' => $products_array[$p][24],
                'meta_title' => $products_array[$p][1] . " | " . $products_array[$p][23] . " | xxxxx.nl",
                'meta_description' => "xxx.",
                'categories' => array('0' => $cat_new_prod1[(string)( $products_array[$p][0])],
                                      '1' => $cat_new_prod2[(string)( $products_array[$p][0])],
                                      '2' => $cat_new_prod3[(string)( $products_array[$p][0])],
                                      '3' => $cat_new_prod4[(string)( $products_array[$p][0])],
                                      '4' => $cat_new_prod5[(string)( $products_array[$p][0])]
                                     )
               );
  try {
    $new_product_id = $model->create($type,$product_attribute_set_id,$sku,$data);
  } catch (Exception $e) { // sku already used
    userErrorHandler(E_USER_WARNING, $e->getMessage(), $e->getFile(), $e->getLine(), "");
    continue;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

see Magmi wiki "[Project origins](http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Project_Origins)" entry, and you'll understand why it takes so much time.

Magmi [Datapump API](http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Magmi_Datapump_API) is perfectly suited for adapting your script with little modification

Comment: Thanks, I go to try to use Magmi also for new products, but I always keep my program (even slow) for situations where Magmi/Martinez fails (reading the forums). I will let you know if all works well (very curieus).

Comment: I have heard from my customer that a normal product import in admin takes the same time (so compared with that I am satisfied with my program, runs only the first time slow, but next nights there are only a few new products). But I go to try Magmi, hopefully it will go well for images too (also a problem in the normal import in admin).

Comment: Dear Dweeves, you are an excellent programmer. Everything works with Magmi, images and extra images (media-gallery plugin). But I had a problem with 'root' directory as many users have that problem I read. My program (cron) runs in root + subdirectory and Magmi takes this as new 'root', so I had to change field magdir in ImageAttributeItemProcessor. Also I had to change function ingest in Magmi_ProductImport_DataPump to return $res, to determine if product was really added to take own/extra actions after. I keep my own program for things maybe not possible in Magmi when necessary.